# the different usage of applyMiddle in Redux

Tags: redux, redux-thunk

I can see there are two ways to call applyMiddleware.

The first one is

```
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
const middleware = [ thunk ]
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(...middleware)
)
```

the other one is

```
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
let store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk))
```

so when should I use the first one and when should I use the second one?
thanks

Comment: they are completely identical ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are pretty much completely identical. The first example is a little more robust, in that it would be easier to add a second middleware if you wanted (by having two elements in the `const middleware` array). But the second one is shorter and does exactly the same thing, and works great if you only need to use one middleware.